# Drupal content sections

Tags: drupal

totally new to drupal is there a way to split content into sections and have navigation for those sections i.e. about us

about us
-opening times
-contact
-history

whats on
-this month
-this year

etc any advice would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to make an About Us page and add it to a menu, then make the sub pages and add those as sub-menu items below About Us. See [Customizing site navigation with menus](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/menu) for more detailed instructions.

Comment: Is it possible to have different menus for different pages?